# Passing the address of string objects to functions

Tags: c++

I've been reading C++ Primer Plus and the first exercise of Chapter 8 requires me to pass a string via address to a function that then prints the string. Then another function prints the string a number of times equal to the number of times the function has been called, unless a second argument (type int) is equal to 0. I have no clue how to get it to print the actual string instead of the address. I've tried the dereferencing operator but that results in an error.

```
    /*  Write a function that normally takes 1 argument, the address of a string, and prints that string once.
    However, if a second, type int, argument is provided and is nonzero, the function should print the
    string a number of times equal to the number of times that function has been called at that point.
    (the number of times the function has been called is not equal to the int argument)
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

//global variables
int times_called = 0;

//function prototypes
void print_str(const string * str);
void print_str(const string * str, int i);

int main()
{
    string str = "Gotta catch'em all!";
    string * pstr = &str;
    print_str(pstr);
    print_str(pstr);
    print_str(pstr, 1);
    print_str(pstr, 0);

    system("PAUSE");
}

void print_str(const string * str)
{
    cout << str;
    cout << endl;
}

void print_str(const string * str, int i)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count <= times_called; count++)
        {
            cout << str;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << str;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: did you notice that times_called is always ZERO? so there will be no difference between print_str(...,1) and print_str(..., 0)

Comment: I forgot to include that question. How do I get the function to print the string, instead of the address of the string.

Comment: How exactly did you try the dereference operator, and what error did you get?

Comment: you also forgot the derefence operator, try cout << *str ;

Comment: I tried "cout << *str"
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: try changing the string header to `<string>` instead of `<string.h>`.

Comment: bkVnet, that was the issue. I didn't realize that <string> and <string.h> were different. Thank you!

Comment: Yes they are different, `<string.h>` is for C-strings while `<string>` is for the C++ `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While dereferencing the string and using `#include <string>` was already [explained by Blake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198819/passing-the-address-of-string-objects-to-functions/37198896#37198896), the exercise, if I understood correctly, is about using a single function, not two functions. I think, they meant something along these lines ([code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/TcfsLQ)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_str(std::string const * _str, int _flag = 0){
 static int count_call = 0;
 ++count_call;
 int count_print = _flag ? count_call : 1;

 while(count_print--)
  std::cout << *_str << std::endl;
}

int main(){
 std::string str{"Hello, world!"};

 print_str(&str);
 print_str(&str);
 print_str(&str);
 std::cout << std::endl;

 print_str(&str, 1);
 std::cout << std::endl;

 print_str(&str);

 return (0);
}
```

Program output:

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!

Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!

Hello, world!
```

Comment: I interpreted the exercise as using overloaded functions, but this works too. Thank you! I couldn't believe it was something as simple as the header file being the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deference your string.  You also need to change `#include <string.h>` to `#include <string>` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_str( const std::string* str ) {
    std::cout << *str << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello world!";
    print_str( &str );
    return 0;
}
```

Execution example:
https://ideone.com/AGSk1k

Comment: Using the code given it still results in an error on my end.
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: `#include <string.h>` needs to be `#include <string>` instead

Answer (score 0):

This is my take....
Since the number of calls determines the number of prints and not the int argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print(const string * arr){
  cout << *arr << endl;
}

void print(const string * arr, int n){

  if(n != 0)
      print(arr);
}

int main()
{
  string sentence;
  cout << "Enter a random sentence:\n";
  getline(cin, sentence);
  string * pt_str = &sentence;
  cout << endl << "Using the print function to display your string:\n";
  print(pt_str);
  print(pt_str,3);

  return 0;
}
```